# Most pragmatic method for formatting an ill-formatted date (Objective-C, Cocoa Touch)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am retrieving pretty badly formatted date stamps from the internet, examples:

```
sun apr 22 19:57:10 2012
thu apr 5 10:13:44 2012
```

Preferably I'd like:

```
22 April 2012 19:57:10
5 April 2012 10:13:44
```

Is there a straightforward method of feeding the bad date into a datestamp and then laying it out in a traditional method (as in an SQL query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For the format specification see [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
    NSString *date1 = @"sun apr 22 19:57:10 2012";
    NSString *date2 = @"thu apr 5 10:13:44 2012";

    //Release this later if not using ARC
    NSDateFormatter *dformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dformatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d H:m:s yyyy"];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dformatter dateFromString:date1]);
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dformatter dateFromString:date2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Excellent class.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use NSDateformatter. Check the standard the server is using to provide the date format, and replicate the behavior with your NSDateformatter instance.